# Would BMP7 introduced to a Petri dish with cartilage cause chondrocytes to replicate?

Tags: cell-culture, growth-media, cartilage

Chondrocytes are the cells that make up cartilage. As I understand it, the best growth factor that signals replication of chondrocytes is Bone morphogenetic protein 7.

If supplied with a sufficient source of nutrients and a growth factor, would those chondrocytes begin to replicate?

If you prepare a Petri dish full of blood and cartilage and add BMP7, would the cartilage start to grow? Are those two questions the same?

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome Delaney Fitzpatrick.

[BMP7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_morphogenetic_protein_7) - Bone morphogenetic protein 7 - Plays a role in cartilage homeostasis.

**Chondrocytes** - A cell which has secreted the matrix of cartilage and become embedded in it.

Chondrocytes therefore make cartilage. Cartilage unfortunately has a poor regeneration capacity.

[BMP7 stimulates Chondrocyte division](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-27602-y)

Naturally the question then becomes, does BMP7 also increase cartilage production?

[A paper from 2009](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19855958/) - Chondrocytes that expressed increased levels of BMP7 in defected rabbit knees showed statistically significant repair when compared to controls.

Although an early study, it does suggest that BMP7 may improve cartilage repair.